# Can you tell me where i did mistake

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

```java
package hrmInfoModule;
       import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
       import org.openqa.selenium.By;    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;    import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
       public class Hrmlogin {
        
    public WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void openbrowser()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Software\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver =  new ChromeDriver ();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void login() throws InterruptedException
    {
        String Url="https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/";
        String ID ="Admin";
        String Pswrd="admin123";
        driver.get(Url);
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername"));
        login.sendKeys(ID);
        WebElement paswrd = driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"));
        paswrd.sendKeys(Pswrd);
        WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));
        btn.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    
    @Test
    public WebElement Admin() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement Admin = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='menu_admin_viewAdminModule']")));
        return Admin;
    }
    
    @Test
    public WebElement JobTitle(WebElement Admin) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement job = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu_admin_viewAdminModule']//following-sibling::ul/li[2]/a"));
        WebElement jobtitles = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu_admin_viewAdminModule']//following-sibling::ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a"));
        Actions act= new Actions(driver); 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        act.moveToElement(Admin).moveToElement(job).moveToElement(jobtitles).click().build().perform();
        WebElement AddBtn= driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//input[@value='Add']")));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        AddBtn.click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='jobTitle_jobTitle']"))).sendKeys("Manager");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='jobTitle_jobDescription']"))).sendKeys("zxc");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='jobTitle_note']"))).sendKeys("jobTitle_note");
        WebElement SaveBtn= driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//input[@value='Save']")));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        SaveBtn.click();
        return job;
    }
    
    @Test
    public void PayGrade(WebElement job) throws InterruptedException
    {
        //WebElement job = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu_admin_viewAdminModule']//following-sibling::ul/li[2]/a"));
        WebElement payGrade = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu_admin_viewAdminModule']//following-sibling::ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/a"));
        Actions act= new Actions(driver); 
        act.moveToElement(job).moveToElement(payGrade).click().build().perform();
        WebElement AddPayBtn= driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//input[@value='Add']")));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        AddPayBtn.click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='payGrade_name']"))).sendKeys("INR");
        WebElement SavePayBtn= driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//input[@value='Save']")));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        SavePayBtn.click();
    }
    
    @AfterTest
    public void teardown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }    }
```

**In above code TestNG passing only one Test named as Login(). Can anyone tell me please why is it so?
How to improve this code and run all tests in a series.**

Comment: Because you open url in `login()` test. In the `@AfterTest` method browser is closed. Browser starts before `Admin()` test but URL is never opened

Comment: So.. abhishek agarwal could test if you are right Fenio, by simply switching off the login() test ?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I get the following log:

```
PASSED: login
FAILED: PayGrade
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [PayGrade] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebElement].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
```

I do not think put `WebElement job` as parameter of `PayGrade(WebElement job)` is right, so try to fix this kind of codes.

**EDIT 1:**

Details in code comments:

```java
package hrmInfoModule;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Hrmlogin {

    public WebDriver driver;
    
    /*
     * put common xpath string here
     */
    String xJob = "//a[@id='menu_admin_Job']";
    String xJobTitles = "//a[@id='menu_admin_viewJobTitleList']";
    String xPayGrade = "//a[@id='menu_admin_viewPayGrades']";

    @BeforeTest
    public void openbrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Software\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test (priority = 0)
    public void testLogin() throws InterruptedException {
        String Url = "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/";
        String ID = "Admin";
        String Pswrd = "admin123";
        driver.get(Url);
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername"));
        login.sendKeys(ID);
        WebElement paswrd = driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"));
        paswrd.sendKeys(Pswrd);
        WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));
        btn.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    
    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void testAdmin() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement admin = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='menu_admin_viewAdminModule']")));
        /**
         * Notice:
         * 1. If there are no effective steps in this function, it should be removed.
         * 2. click() is more stable than Actions.moveTo()
         */
        admin.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Test (priority = 2)
    public void testJobTitle() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement job = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xJob));
        WebElement jobTitles = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xJobTitles));
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        act.moveToElement(job).moveToElement(jobTitles).click().build().perform();
        
        WebElement AddBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//input[@value='Add']")));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        AddBtn.click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='jobTitle_jobTitle']"))).sendKeys("Manager");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='jobTitle_jobDescription']"))).sendKeys("zxc");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='jobTitle_note']"))).sendKeys("jobTitle_note");
        WebElement SaveBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//input[@value='Save']")));
        SaveBtn.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Test (priority = 3)
    public void testPayGrade() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement job = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xJob));
        WebElement payGrade = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPayGrade));
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(job).moveToElement(payGrade).click().build().perform();
        WebElement AddPayBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//input[@value='Add']")));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        AddPayBtn.click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='payGrade_name']"))).sendKeys("INR");
        WebElement SavePayBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//input[@value='Save']")));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        SavePayBtn.click();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion..but then how can i call WebElements 'Admin'  and 'Job'in different TestCase like JobTitle and  PayGrade.Should i locate admin and job type of elements again and again according to its usage?

Comment: @abhishek agarwal  Please re-locate elements in different `@test` methods. The suggestion is based on two factors: 1) test methods isolation without affecting each other 2) page operations may cause DOM change, re-location will be more secure. Moreover, maybe you need to learn more [TestNG basics](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Comment: The Hierarchy of WebElement is Admin---->Job-----> Job Titles also parallely Pay Grade. so i need to relocate Elements i.e. Admin then Job then only i can able to locate Job Titles and Pay Grade. As per given suggestion if i  relocate elements in different-2 test methods then it will run successfully for Job Titles but Pay Grade Test case it will not run successfully. therfore, i need to pass web element. Hope you get my message

Comment: @abhishekagarwal I have modified the answer. Hope useful for you, if so click the Useful Button in front of this answer please : )

Comment: I'm thankfull to you for answering continuously. your answer partially helpful but still my question remains same as in "testJobTitles" and "testPayGrade" methods you are rewriting a code for WebElement "Job". so i'm thinking is there any kind of way to overcome this rewriting.

Comment: @abhishekagarwal If you can make sure that Element "Job" is the same throughout the class `Hrmlogin` during testing, you can place `Element Job` as global variable of class `Hrmlogin`, so that `Element Job` will only need to be instantiated once, and Job can be used in "testJobTitles" and "testPayGrade" methods.

Comment: Hi, @abhishekagarwal , please [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [Vote up it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) , if this solves your problem. It will help others and myself :)